# Solutions to a periodic modular structure

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given $n$ primes $p_{0},p_{1},\dots,p_{n-1}\in(2^{b},2^{b+1})$ for a fixed $b \geq 4$ such that $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}p_{i} > 2^{2^{b}}$.

Is it possible to find $N,d > 0$ such that for any given integer $a \in (2^{2^{b-1}},2^{2^{b}})$, when we define $r_{i} = a\pmod {p_{i\pmod n}}$ $\forall i\geq 0$, the following structure holds $\forall i\geq 0$: 
$$r_{i+1} = r_{i}^{d}\pmod N?$$

Comment: I am failing to parse your expressions. What variable is governed by your first $\forall$ sign? You said in the first line that $a$ and $b$ are both fixed. And the $r_i$ are introduced without definition.

Comment: Is it clear now?